# JavaScript Audio src - should it point to a file?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, google-translate

I am doing the following, but it is not playing:

```
var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=Whatismyname";
audio_obj = new Audio(url); 
audio_obj.play();
```

If I use a URL that ends with `.mp3`, it plays fine. If I use Google TTS service, then it doesn't play. Could anyone please tell me how to make it work with Google TTS?

Comment: What do you mean by `google tts service`?

Comment: I have tried it on Chrome after disabling referrer. Still does nt work :-(

Comment: google has this text to speech service, that converts the text to mp3 and plays it. We have some service similar to that. I need to use that service on the front end to play the audio.

Comment: Google sometimes will think it is a robot and won't allow you to play the file, I think.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Got it resolved. I disabled referrers, but I kept another browser window open, that has referrers enabled. So thats' why it didnt work.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. Also, you can post your answer below and help the community!

Comment: To solve this problem, you need to close all Chrome windows, open the chrome window by using the following on command prompt.
/path to your chrome.exe/Chrome --no-referrers &

This will allow the javascript to use urls that do not end with file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need to close all Chrome windows, open the chrome window by using the following on command prompt. /path to your chrome.exe/Chrome --no-referrers & This will allow the javascript to use urls that do not end with file extensions.

(from user1401976's comment)